# How can I add react project to an existing jquery/vanilla js project?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, reactjs

I have a main/hero **website** built with **html+jquery** and **dashboard with react**. Currently dashboard serves from different subdomain `(dashboard.example.com)`and website from `(example.com)`. I would like them to be in same folder such that website would still be `(example.com)` but dashboard would be `(example.com/dashboard)`. Can someone help me how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you can try this trick:

- create new child folder called dashboard inside your public folder, and move index.html with build file react dashboard, inside the dashboard public folder.
- and then load react js build bundle from the move index.html inside dashboard folder.

they will be called into the new folder dashboard in example.com/dashboard

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I have tried this and it works but how can I update the build files automatically? I want to push changes to dashboard repo and update build files automatically in website repo.

Comment: if you have ci cd, you can copy file build or move to the specific folder in the server  automatically with script, if not have access, you can use gulp with gulp api src and gulp api dest on execution npm script for copy file build into other folder project local automatically, and then push on other folder project repository, that i use for my local project repository

Comment: Thanks for the solutions. Before I try these, Can I achieve this with git submodule?

Comment: I don't try this git submodule before, it's nice too, you can use that, but using submodule is mean cloning one project or copying one project to parent project, in your case i see it just need file build react only and file html, and I think if use submodule make your code project can access by public on folder dashboard